# Show file extension in file name

Tags: 12.04, unity, files, file-format

Is there any way to show file suffixes by default at the end of the file name in unity?

For example:
If I have a file called `test.bin`, it is shown as `test` in Unity. I'd like it to be shown as `test.bin` by default in Unity.

Comment: Where in Unity do you want the extension to be displayed?

Comment: In file explorer like Windows Os.

Comment: As far as I know by default Ubuntu shows files with their file extensions. So, if you have created a file `test.bin` then when you will open nautilus your file will be shown as `test.bin` and not just `test`

Comment: @HamidFzM If you have a file called `test.bin`, this it is shown anywhere as `test.bin`: in any file manager, in terminal/console/shell, in Dash, on the desktop, ao. Can you explain exactly where do you see only the name without extension?

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu For example in `/usr/bin` there are some executable files that Ubuntu doesn't show their suffix or windows executables `EXE` files in Ubuntu file explorer!

Comment: @HamidFzM Ubuntu doesn't show their suffix/extension because they don't have any one. See [What's the application extension? (aka .exe, .app, etc.)](http://askubuntu.com/a/366825/147044)